# Environment variable

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I need to install a software called silico.In that software it says

1. Copy the Silico directory tree to an appropriate location
2. Set the environment variable `SILICO_HOME` to point to the silico directory
3. Include `$SILICO_HOME/bin` in your path

eg.  For the C shell

```
setenv SILICO_HOME /apps/scripts/silico1.01
setenv PATH $PATH\:$SILICO_HOME/bin
```

Therefore, I put the silico directory into /usr/local and then I included

```
export SILICO_HOME /usr/local
export PATH $PATH\:$SILICO_HOME/bin
```

in `/.bashrc`. However, when I tried to run, it didn't work. I am new to Ubuntu. Could you please anyone help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Is silico command line or graphics app ? You may need to log out and back in

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a directory named **silico**.

Put the directory in any location, suppose `/opt`

Now your silico directory path will be `/opt/silico`, and there is a `bin` folder in silico dir.

Now open your `~/.bashrc` file and put these line in the end of file.

```
export SILICO_HOME=/opt/silico
export PATH=$PATH:$SILICO_HOME/bin
```

Then restart terminal or execute `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @A.G If one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the bourne family of shells (which includes bash, the default shell on Ubuntu) is different. It is `export var=value`. You also don't need to escape the `:`, but never mind. What you want is:

```
export SILICO_HOME=/usr/local
export PATH="$PATH:$SILICO_HOME/bin"
```

Oh, and I assume you mean `~/.bashrc` (`$HOME/.bashrc`) and not `/.bashrc`.